# "With this going on" and "got a lot going on"

Tags: phrases

Here's a fragment of "[Rocky Balboa - Inspirational Speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPD0z6K0VQY&feature=youtu.be&t=21s)":

> **With this going on**, it's gonna be worse than ever. 
>   - It don't have to be. - Sure it does. 
>   -Why? You **got a lot goin' on**, kid.

And my question is about usage and meaning of "with this going on" and "got a lot going on".

- I noticed that the "with this going on" is used at the beginning of the sentence. But what does it mean and what the rule of its usage? I understand it like this.

  1. There is a case we described/discussed
  2. It happens at the
     moment
  3. The sentence after "with this going on" should be in
     context of mentioned case.
- The phrase "you got a lot going on" is more difficult for me. I understand it as "you have got a lot of interesting things/cases in your life".

Can you please provide me synonyms for those phrases, explanation and example of usage? Thanks!

Comment: You roughly understand what's going on in this conversation.

Comment: Yes. Or "a lot goin' on" might be meant as a compliment, as in "you have a lot of positive attributes" or "you are doing a lot of good things". Compare, for example, "got it goin' on" http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/fountainsofwayne/stacysmom.html

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thank you! Very good explanation and thanks for a link.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Hi! May I ask you to explain the phrase "with this going on"? In case with "a lot going on" and "got it going on" we speak about benefits or positive attributes. But the phrase "with this going on" doesn't refer to any benefits, right? It just means "in this case". Do I understand it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it just means "with all these things happening."  that is, whatever he might have mentioned previously.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thank you! Could you, please, copy your answers to the "Answer" block in order I can check my question as solved.